OpenAI API key with "proj-" prefix not working when read from .env file
I'm working on a Next.js/React/TypeScript project that integrates with the OpenAI API. I've encountered an issue with the new Project-based API keys feature.
Previously, I successfully used this setup:
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

My .env file contained:
OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-xxxxx

However, with the new Project-based API keys (format: sk-proj-xxxxx), this setup no longer works. I'm receiving an invalid_api_key error.
I've noticed that process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY seems to strip the proj- part from the API key when reading it from the .env file.
Oddly enough, using the key as a plain string works fine:
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: "sk-proj-xxxxx",
});

I've scoured the OpenAI documentation and googled the hell out of it but haven't found any solutions. The closest relevant information I found was in the OpenAI Authentication documentation.
Has anyone encountered this problem? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated! :)
My route.ts:
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY, //this seems to be the issue
});

const instructionMessage = {
  role: "system",
  content: `blah blah instructions`,
};

async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { messages } = body;
    const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!openai.apiKey) {
      return new NextResponse("OpenAi Api Key not configured"), { status: 500 };
    }

    if (!messages || messages.length === 0) {
      return new NextResponse("Input Required", { status: 400 });
    }

    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4o-mini",
      messages: [instructionMessage, lastMessage],
    });

    return NextResponse.json(response.choices[0].message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[CODE_ERROR]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
  }
}

export { POST };


You seem to be passing process.env.OPEN_API_KEY as a string

@BackSlash Oops thats from me changing it on the post here. On my codebase its not a string. My bad. I fixed it by just setting a systemwide env variable

Why would you think this is an OpenAI issue? If you've made a change to your .env file and it's not being reflected in your code, it's more likely a dotenv / Next.js issue. An error in those libs is highly unlikely so I can only assume you're editing the wrong .env file, haven't saved changes and / or haven't restarted your Next.js server since making the change

Do some debugging like logging process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY. Change it to something else entirely like OPENAI_API_KEY=TEST and see if that is reflected in your logging

@Phil Did all that, couldnt find the cause, so i just created a systemwide variable and it works. ( the issues only seems to show up with the OpenAI key)
